# How to add Axis labels using networkD3 in R

Tags: r, axis-labels, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I'm making a Sankey diagram using the networkD3 package, I have included my code below. I want to add a title, footnotes, and label both the left side and right side of the diagram. But I'm not sure how to do this as networkD3 has no built in labeling commands

```
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)
Comp_Noncomp<-c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
Category<-c("D","E","F","D","E","F","D","E","F")
Frequency<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
my.data.3<-data.frame(Comp_Noncomp,Category,Frequency)
nodes <- data.frame(name=c(as.character(my.data.3$Comp_Noncomp), as.character(my.data.3$Category)) %>% unique())
my.data.3$IDsource=match(my.data.3$Comp_Noncomp, nodes$name)-1 
my.data.3$IDtarget=match(my.data.3$Category, nodes$name)-1
library(networkD3)
sankeyNetwork(Links = my.data.3, Nodes = nodes,
                     Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                     Value = "Frequency", NodeID = "name", 
                     sinksRight=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the libraries `htmlwidgets` and `htmltools` to add content to this diagram.

For example, if you wanted to add a title:

```
s <- sankeyNetwork(Links = my.data.3,  Nodes = nodes, 
                   Source = "IDsource",  Target = "IDtarget", 
                   Value = "Frequency",  NodeID = "name",  
                   sinksRight=FALSE)

s2 <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(s, htmltools::tags$h1("This is my Title"))
```

[image]

Let's say you wanted to add styles and a subtitle.

```
s3 <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(s, htmltools::tags$h1("This is my Title",
                                                       style="text-align:center;"),
                                 htmltools::tags$h2("This is my Subtitle",
                                                    style="color:#003b70; text-align:center;"))
```

[image]

There are a lot of things you can do with this, but you'll have to explore a bit to figure out exactly what you want and where you want it.

---

---

#### Update based on your comment

Probably the easiest way to add left and right comments would be with the library `manipulateWidget`.

You'll want to revert to your original Sankey diagram, because it will remove any prepended or appended content.

I vertically centered the text on the left side. On the right side, I let the system choose the placement. This way you can see different ways to align the content.

```
s <- sankeyNetwork(Links = my.data.3,  Nodes = nodes, 
                   Source = "IDsource",  Target = "IDtarget", 
                   Value = "Frequency",  NodeID = "name",  
                   sinksRight=FALSE)

leftTx = tags$div( 
  style="max-width: 30vw; padding-bottom: 15px; height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;", 
                  tags$p("This text is on the left side"))
rightTx = tags$p("This text is on the right",
                 style="max-width:30vw")

cS <- combineWidgets(s,
                     title = tags$h1("This is my Title",
                                     style="text-align:center;"),
                     leftCol = leftTx,
                     rightCol = rightTx,
                     nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful, is there anyway I can label the left and right side of the diagram?

Comment: I updated the answer so you could see one way that you can do that.